# Upgraded DDR3 RAM from 2gb to 4gb but windows can't boot with the new one

Tags: memory

[Picture of the previous and new RAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQlEl.jpg)

The laptop is a Toshiba Tecra A11-110 with an intel i5 processor.
I replaced the previous RAM with the new one but then the Windows begins to boot but ms later shuts down and the computer restarts again.
Is the new RAM "incompatible" or something?

Thank you.

Comment: Your old SODIMM module was a 1.35V module. The new one requires 1.5V. I haven’t tried looking for your notebook’s specs though.

Comment: The memory you purchased is not incompatible with your laptop.  While I am willing to say that in a comment, without a link to the Toshiba product page for your laptop, I am not willing to submit an answer.

Comment: I replaced the 4gb DDR3 1,5V with a 4gb DDR3L 1,35V and it's the same thing... What could be? This is the laptop http://www.toshiba.pt/discontinued-products/tecra-a11-110/

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/nILUa7j.jpg